# How to parse HTML data using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am new to parsing HTML data using excel VBA. Below is my code and some sample HTML. Notice in the HTML: pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000016">oles and Responsibilities

I want to open hundreds of similar internal web pages, and find the Roles and Responsibilities section and then start to grab certain data and paste it into various columns.

I've modified my code below, it works now based upon what was recommended.

By the way, just in case this helps others, I did discover a great fix for 'object invoked has disconnected' errors; here is the fix: Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

```
Option Explicit
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub ImportStackOverflowData()
    Dim a As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    'Set ie = New InternetExplorer 'replaced with InternetExplorerMedium to fix error
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium 'this fixes this error: The object invoked has disconnected from its client
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "policy.myurl.com"
    Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set html = ie.document

    Dim tag As IHTMLElement
    Dim tags As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set tags = html.getElementsByClassName("pt-000015")
    For Each tag In tags
        'more logic here
    Next

    Set html = ie.document
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTML SAMPLE:

div class="pt-000015"><p dir="ltr" class="pt-PolicyMajorSectionHead"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000016">R</span><a id="Roles" class="pt-000002"></a><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000016">oles and Responsibilities</span></p></div><p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal"><span class="pt-000000"> </span></p><p dir="ltr" class="pt-Policy1stLevelSubhead"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000005"><b>Key Data Governance Roles</b></span><a id="56GeneralSectionTitle_Optional_L2" class="pt-000002"></a></p><a id="56GeneralSectionTitle_Optional_L2" class="pt-000002"></a><p dir="ltr" class="pt-PolicyText-000006"><span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000007">Data governance is a shared responsibility.</span><

Comment: `pt-000015` is a class element, not an id?

Comment: You can try `.getElementsByClassName` - instead of `getElementById`.

Comment: It's not XML, it's HTML.  Question title is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
html.getElementsByClassName("pt-000015")
```

It is plural as returns a collection and needs Name on the end.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed, just some info that gets me past this roadblock. I really appreciate the help.